# How can i get youtube video link after the video file was uploaded?

Tags: c#, .net, youtube-api, youtube-data-api, google-api-dotnet-client

This is the event when the video file uploaded:

```
public static TimeSpan time = new TimeSpan();
Video objects = null;

private void videosInsertRequest_ResponseReceived(Video obj)
{
    System.Timers.Timer aTimer;
    aTimer = new System.Timers.Timer();
    aTimer.Elapsed += aTimer_Elapsed;
    aTimer.Interval = 10000;
    aTimer.Enabled = false;
    uploadstatus = obj.Status.UploadStatus;
    if (uploadstatus == "uploaded")
    {
        fileuploadpercentages = 100; 
        stopwatch.Stop();
        var milliseconds = stopwatch.ElapsedMilliseconds;
        time = stopwatch.Elapsed;
        time = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(Math.Round(time.TotalSeconds));
        uploadstatus = "file uploaded successfully";
        string[] lines = File.ReadAllLines(userVideosDirectory + "\\UploadedVideoFiles.txt");
        File.WriteAllLines(userVideosDirectory + "\\UploadedVideoFiles.txt", lines.Skip(1));
        if (Form1.uploadedFilesList.Count > 0)
            Form1.uploadedFilesList.RemoveAt(0);                
    }
    if (uploadstatus == "Completed")
    {

    }

    objects = obj;
}
```

I used a break point and i see that the variable obj have some properties one of them is id. But there is no link property or something that show the link.

This is how i'm uploading the video but i'm not sure if it will help i need to find the uploaded video link after the upload finished.

```
private void UploadVideo(string FileName, string VideoTitle, string VideoDescription)
{
    try
    {
        var youtubeService = new YouTubeService(new BaseClientService.Initializer()
        {
            HttpClientInitializer = credential,
            ApplicationName = Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().GetName().Name
        });

        video.Snippet = new VideoSnippet();
        video.Snippet.Title = VideoTitle;
        video.Snippet.Description = VideoDescription;
        video.Snippet.Tags = new string[] { "tag1", "tag2" };
        video.Status = new VideoStatus();
        video.Status.PrivacyStatus = "public";
        using (var fileStream = new FileStream(FileName, FileMode.Open))
        {

            const int KB = 0x400;
            var minimumChunkSize = 256 * KB;

            var videosInsertRequest = youtubeService.Videos.Insert(video,
                "snippet,status", fileStream, "video/*");
            videosInsertRequest.ProgressChanged += videosInsertRequest_ProgressChanged;
            videosInsertRequest.ResponseReceived += videosInsertRequest_ResponseReceived;
            // The default chunk size is 10MB, here will use 1MB.
            videosInsertRequest.ChunkSize = minimumChunkSize * 3;
            dt = DateTime.Now;
            totalBytes = fileStream.Length;
            videosInsertRequest.Upload();
        }
    }
    catch (Exception errors)
    {
        string errorss = errors.ToString();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In the [.net sample](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/code_samples/dotnet#upload_a_video), after the video is uploaded there's some code to check what I believe is the video's ID:

```
void videosInsertRequest_ResponseReceived(Video video)
    {
      Console.WriteLine("Video id '{0}' was successfully uploaded.", video.Id);
    }
```

So you should be able to pass in your `video` object and get its ID.

Alternatively, you could try looking at your recent uploads by using [`playlists.list()`](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/playlists/list) and specify your uploads playlist ID, then get the ID of the newest video.